# Twilio callback status of an outbound call is always 'completed'

Tags: callback, salesforce, twilio

I'm trying to create an IVR Phone tree through REST API in Salesforce (Twilio API). The problem is that I can't catch any other callback status except 'completed'.

If the call was cancelled or there was no response on this call, Twilio sends a call response with 'completed' status anyway.

Moreover, a customer gets a voicemail with a recorded 'welcome' message and first phone tree question after an unsuccessful call attempt.

There is a code sample of how calls are created :

```
TwilioRestClient client = new TwilioRestClient(TwilioSID, TwilioToken);
Map<String,String> params = new Map<String, String>(); 

String webURL = webServerURL;

params.put('To', phone);  
params.put('From', phoneFrom);   
params.put('Url', webURL); 
params.put('Method', 'GET'); 
params.put('FallbackUrl', webURL);
params.put('FallbackMethod', 'GET');
params.put('StatusCallback', webURL);
if (!System.Test.isRunningTest()) {
    try {
        TwilioCall call = client.getAccount().getCalls().create(params);
    } catch(Exception ex) {
    }
}
```

In addition, I was trying to add 'StatusCallbackEvent' parameter (link to Twilio documentation - https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml#callstatus-values) :

```
params.put('StatusCallbackEvent', 'busy canceled completed failed no-answer');

// and other optiions like :
// params.put('StatusCallbackEvent', 'busy');
// params.put('StatusCallbackEvent', 'canceled');
// params.put('StatusCallbackEvent', 'completed');
// params.put('StatusCallbackEvent', 'failed');
// params.put('StatusCallbackEvent', 'no-answer');
```

But there was no any difference in a callback status after failed calls.

How should I make calls to get Twilio call responses with all finalized statuses ('busy', 'failed', 'no-answer', etc ...) ?

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

When you set a URL for the `StatusCallback` then by default you will only receive callbacks when the call is "completed". A completed call may have different reasons for being completed though, such as "busy", "failed", "no-answer" or plain "completed"  and you can read that value from the `CallStatus` parameter that is sent to the URL.

You can subscribe to other events though, as you tried. The only thing is you were trying to subscribe to the potential statuses and not the events themselves.

For a call [you can subscribe to "initiated", "ringing", "answered" and "completed"](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/api/call#statuscallbackevent). So try:

```
params.put('StatusCallbackEvent', 'initiated ringing answered completed');
```

Comment: thanks for the clarification about 'StatusCallback' and 'StatusCallbackEvent'. But it doesn't explain why dropped/unanswered calls have 'completed' status instead of 'cancelled'/'no-answer' and my customer gets a voicemail of the call that he doesn't respond.

It would be great if you have some information about this. Because I don't understand how I can influence on Twilio responses any other way. Is it possible to cofigure it in Twillo account ? I couldn't find such settings on its side.

Comment: I am guessing you are trying to connect a call using `<Dial>`? Have you checked the `DialCallStatus` parameter that is sent to the `action` URL?

Comment: No, I'm not using <Dial> at all. TWiML instructions contain only <Say>, <Play> and <Gather> verbs (as I mentioned earlier it's an IVR phone tree). Making a call is carried out only by standard methods provided by Twilio package.

Example in the description above.

Comment: Oh, I see. When voicemail answers a call it is counted as an answered call. You could try [answering machine detection](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/answering-machine-detection) to understand whether a human or a machine answers the phone and perhaps that would avoid this issue?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, I need to check who picked up the phone (machine or human), and it can be the reason of the issue. Is it right ?

Because I tested it earlier by myself - started a call on my phone number and cancelled it manually. But the response was 'completed'

Comment: If you use the answering machine detection then it will tell you whether the call was answered by a machine, a human, a fax or unknown and you can handle it how you like (though, since the call was answered, it's final status will be "complete"). When you say you cancelled the call, what response was completed?

Comment: I mean next : 
When I cancelled a call, Twilio had sent me a response of this call on 'StatusCallback' URL and 'CallStatus' parameter was 'completed'.

Comment: Hmm, that is unexpected. If you are seeing results like that I recommend you get in touch with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) and supply them some CallSids that were incorrect. They will be able to explain what is going on.

Comment: thanks for your answers. I think I'll follow your advice.

Comment: No worries, hope you get it sorted.

Comment: Anyone can update this? I am having the same problem that: No matter I reject or not answer the call, the CallStatus is always Complete...

Comment: @LinFeng it is likely better that you start a new question rather than try to discuss this in the comments. Please try to describe your application and how you are reading the status. Thanks.